# Unclosed token when parsing a string to an ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I need to parse a string to an ElementTree using python. However I am getting an error.

```
>   File "script.py", line 100, in clientthread
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1312, in XML
    return parser.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1671, in close
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1523, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unclosed token: line 21, column 1
```

It is saying that the xml has an unclosed token, which is weird because I have validated my XML using several online xml validation services to validate the syntax.

I also tried the `xml.dom.minidom` library which resulted in the same error.

Could it maybe be something else that is causing the error, or am I missing something?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <dserver-log-message>
            <d-server-system-id>1111</d-server-system-id>
            <message-id>87</message-id>
            <event-id>1</event-id>
            <event-name>Alarm received</event-name>
            <alarm-id-32>66636</alarm-id-32>
            <date>2022-01-24</date>
            <time>13:30:05</time>
            <alarm-source-radio-id>5573</alarm-source-radio-id>
            <alarmbron-user-id>2</alarmbron-user-id>
            <alarm-source-name-of-user-alarmpoint-or-personnel>Smile ID</alarm-source-name-of-user-alarmpoint-or-personnel>
            <alarm-reason-id>0</alarm-reason-id>
            <alarm-reason-text>Alarm</alarm-reason-text>
            <group-id>1</group-id>
            <group-name>showroom</group-name>
            <paging-text-message-line-breaks-replaced-with-spaces>Alarm Smile ID ATOM </paging-text-message-line-breaks-replaced-with-spaces>
            <paging-text-message-first-line>Alarm</paging-text-message-first-line>
            <paging-text-message-second-line>Smile ID</paging-text-message-second-line>
            <paging-text-message-third-line>ATOM</paging-text-message-third-line>
            <battery-status-of-alarm-transmitter-ok-or-low-voltage>Battery OK</battery-status-of-alarm-transmitter-ok-or-low-voltage>
            <equipment-type-alarm-source-ID>16</equipment-type-alarm-source-ID>
            <equipment-type-alarm-source-text>ATOM</equipment-type-alarm-source-text>
    </dserver-log-message>
```

My code:

```
    import socket
    import sys
    import thread
    import socket
    import sys
    import urllib
    import requests
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import mysql.connector
    import smtplib
    import ssl
    
    
    TCP_IP = "10.2.2.7"
    TCP_PORT = 11223
    
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                         socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # TCP
    sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    sock.listen(10)
    print('Socket now listening')
    
    
    
    # Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
    def clientthread(conn):
        # Sending message to connected  client
        # infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
        while True:
    
            # Receiving from client
            data = conn.recv(1024)
    
            if not data:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))
    
        # came out of loop
        conn.close()
        print('Connection closed')
    
    
    # now keep talking with the client
    while 1:
        # wait to accept a connection - blocking call
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        #  print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    
        # start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the
        # function.
        thread.start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn,))
    
    sock.close()
```

Comment: This is hard to reproduce. since we don't have access to your network/sockets/SQL server. The XML that you show in the question is OK.

Comment: Btw, it appears that you use Python 2. Do you have to?

Comment: @mzjn Unfortunately yes,  I have to use python 2. The network this script will be running on uses Python 2.

Comment: before the line `tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))` do `print(data)` - you will find out an invalid xml I believe ..

Comment: **Note** that you try to parse the xml inside a loop , maybe you want to do it once after the loop is done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `conn.recv(1024)` reads at most 1024 bytes, resulting in not reading my XML completely because it is bigger than 1024 bytes. Changing the byte size to a bigger number solved my problem.